# Integration with Robot framework's keyword management for Selenium Object Pattern Design

Tags: java, testing, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I have been shopping for tools for UI automation quite a while.  And, the reason being so cautious is to prevent from shooting myself in the foot.  The link below best describes my fear 
http://gojko.net/2010/04/13/how-to-implement-ui-testing-without-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-2/

I am now quite certain that I can going to meet the goal by leveraging Selenium2.0 with Page Object Design(that takes care of technical activity part) in conjunction with Robot Framework's keyword feature (that takes care of the work flow and rule parts).  So, what happen would be I will map user defined keywords with the corresponding Page methods and then use to keywords to design test plans on robot framework

However, I have not found a solution on how to map a user defined keyword to the methods from the corresponding Page Object Designed method in Java.

A guidance on how would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's being a while before I did around google search on this topic. There is actually some matching articles which did not exist before.

http://www.beer30.org/?p=54 (Models Page Object through RF spreadsheet)
http://imsardine.simplbug.com/note/robotframework/page-object.html (Directly import Page Object into RF spreadsheet, but concluded could not be a good idea because keyword is based on flat hierarchy whereas Page Object is inhereted)

Comment: Daniel, it seems the latter link is gone/moved? returns 404.

Comment: Hi David, try this
http://www.beer30.org/2012/05/26/using-the-page-object-pattern-with-robot-framework/

Comment: Hi Daniel, that link is same destination as first link. The 2nd link (imsardine.simplbug.com), does that point to the same thing too originally, or that went to some other article? Just checking to see if there was a different "article/post" that has since gone offline.

Comment: Hi David, first link does indeed returns 404 as the link provided first place is incomplete.  2nd link works.  Try google using "robotframework pageobject", you should be able to see it in the first matched item

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think this is the 2nd link when searching via Google to find the correct or updated URL: http://imsardine.simplbug.com/note/robotframework/page-object/page-object.html. I know the beer30 link is fine, I was referring to other link.

Answer (score 4):

Our organization developed a framework to support this: https://github.com/ncbi/robotframework-pageobjects.

I wrote about the experience of implementing this here:
http://www.kahunacohen.com/2014/12/03/new-testing-paradigm-robotframework-pageobjects/

Answer (score 1):

There's some info here that might be helpful: http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/how-to-structure-a-scalable-and-maintainable-acceptance-test-suite/

If not, then a good place to ask would be the robotframework users group: http://groups.google.com/group/robotframework-users

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to what Ruslan said,I have been working on an automation tool called **TOSCA Test suite**. Its brilliant for UI testing and works like magic. However, I would advice you to stay away from it if you hate automation tools that are not steeped in scripts (by scripts I mean coding). Tosca lets you capture screens from your application using a inbuilt mechanism called TOSCA Wizard which saves the application screen in a .xml file. This later can be imported inside your testing workspace and can be used to create scripts.

This tool behaves as a test management tool as well and lets you maintain requirement, created testcase flows, automate testcases, execute them and also helps you in reporting the results.

You can find more information about this tool at http://www.tricentis.com/en/home

Try this and let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote up a simple example showing a conversion of Java page object to Robot Framework pure user keyword/resource files format (all done at user level, no code). I did it as found the existing examples a bit too complex and less intuitive to those who come from working with page objects in actual code, or who follow page object examples that were given in code. This here more closer mirrors the code implementation

https://github.com/daluu/robotframework-simple-page-object-example

it does not cover inheritance of page objects and separate test related classes that test cases might inherit from. Perhaps that's for a future example that's more complicated.

I will say however that basic inheritance could be mimicked with resource files referencing one another. You just might not get the level of scoping granularity that you would get in code is all (public, private, protected, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that Robot framework is a best choice for UI testing. It suites better for functional integration testing when a complex system or component of the system is under test. For example I'm using it to test a business rules engine. I send different events to the engine and verify if the system was turned to an appropriate state.

Did you check any other UI testing tools like [Watir](http://watir.com/), [Tosca](http://www.froglogic.com/?gclid=CPOctN2JwLMCFaTMtAodbHoAHA) or [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/)? I find the last one the most interesting for the way how it addresses components on the page (relative to other elements). And it doesn't require any special tags for UI components.